# After power outage, my NAS drive isn't automounting

Tags: raspbian, boot, hard-drive, mount, fstab

I have a RPi 1 Model B, configured as a torrent box, running Wheezy with Webmin, deluge torrent and Sickrage. To store the medias, i put a 2tb external hard drive on my router Linksys EA6400 and i mount this drive as CFIS. My problem is that when i have a power outage (in Brazil summer they happen so much) the router drive unmounts and deluge starts the torrents again downloading the medias to root partition. My sdcard gets full and stops the system. I believe that this happen because the RPi starts up before the router and when the fstab try mount the drive, he is not ready. But is just an opinion. Someone can help me?

Comment: Your theory seems sound, but I think if you have been using Webmin your options for fixing the problem are pretty limited.  You could arrange a service to, e.g., depend upon the mounting of a remote filesystem but if Webmin didn't do this in the first place and you keep using it, there's no reason it won't just put things back to the (wrong) way they were before later.

Comment: Do you think that Webmin is the reason of the problem? I use the Webmin just to simplify. I use the SSH (putty) to make all setups in the system.

Comment: I've never used Webmin, but since you referred to it I presumed that's how you set up the other stuff you mention for the torrenting.  If so, then it has configured [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) services for you, but in a way that's not conducive to your set-up (with the remote storage).  So either it has a way around that, or it doesn't in which case you will perhaps have to stop using Webmin for that stuff and do it yourself.

Comment: What can i do? Im totally lost :(

Comment: You could ask on [Webmin's forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/discussion/600155/) about this issue; this should confirm or deny that you can change the configuration that way.  If not, you will have to start asking about how to set up services at boot yourself.